# SQL unterminated quoted string \i: missing required argument

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run this script with the command "\ i c: /users/public/giro_d'italia2014.sql" as I did with other scripts only that this time sql seems not to do something right ...
this is what it says: unterminated quoted string
\ i: missing required argument ..... I tried to look for this problem but I could not find anything .... can you help me please?
this is the script ...

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS giro_d'italia2014 CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA giro_d'italia2014;
SET search_path TO giro_d'italia2014;

CREATE TABLE ciclista(
    id_ciclista INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nome ciclista VARCHAR ,
    squadra CHAR(3),
    nazione CHAR(3));

CREATE TABLE tappa(
    nome_tappa VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    km INT,
    tipologia {'pianeggiante'|'alta montagna'|'media montagna'|'cronometro a squadre'|'cronometro individuale'|'cronoscalata'} );

CREATE TABLE ordine_arrivo(
    id_ciclista INT,
    nome_tappa VARCHAR ,
    ordine INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_ciclista, nome_tappa));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't include a single quote `'` in an identifier unless you use [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS "giro_d'italia2014" CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA "giro_d'italia2014";
SET search_path TO "giro_d'italia2014";
```

But I strongly recommend to use identifiers that do **not** need to be quoted.

---

this

```
tipologia {'pianeggiante'|'alta montagna'|'media montagna'|'cronometro a squadre'|'cronometro individuale'|'cronoscalata'} );
```

is also invalid SQL. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with that. if you are trying to limit the values that are allowed, use a check constraint:

```sql
(
  ...
  tipologia text not null, 
  check tipologia in ('pianeggiante', 'alta montagna', 'media montagna', 'cronometro a squadre', 'cronometro individuale', 'cronoscalata') 
);
```

---

The use of the `char` data type is also [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: thank you for your help, i followed your suggestions but the problem persists